# What is the difference between {} and () in calling a function?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I recently saw a new method, at least to me, for calling functions in Lua and that is by using the curly braces {}, certainly if the parameter was a table. Take this function as an example of what I want to examine:

```
function test(table)
    for _, i in pairs(table) do
        print(i);
    end
end

test{"What", "is", "the", "difference?"};
```

In calling the function **test()**, we used the curly braces "{}" instead of the normal braces "()".

So my questions go, what is the difference between those two? Which is better in performance? When should I use one rather than the other? Why was such a way like this created while the normal braces did the job?

Comment: In addition to the answers you got, test{} is not equivalent to test(). Test has one parameter (table) and passing more than one argument will silently ignore the rest, while {} creates a table as a single object that contains all values.  So, test {1,2,3} is not the same as test(1,2,3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua provides two syntactic sugars for function arguments. Their purpose is convenience only.

You may choose whatever you (and your colleagues) prefer in terms of convenience , readability and your software design. Performance-wise there is no difference.

If your only argument is a single literal string or a single new table (table constructor!) you may omit the parenthesis.

From the Lua reference manual:

[2.5.8 – Function Calls](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.8)

> Arguments have the following syntax:

```
args ::= `(´ [explist] `)´
args ::= tableconstructor 
args ::= String
```

> All argument expressions are evaluated before the call. A call
>   of the form `f{fields}` is syntactic sugar for `f({fields})`; that is, the
>   argument list is a **single new table**. A call of the form `f'string'` (or
>   `f"string"` or `f[[string]])` is syntactic sugar for `f('string')`; that is,
>   the argument list is a **single literal string**.